# Error: 'c' is used outside the scope of its declaration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

An application has a page of statistics representing dozens of calculations. To avoid duplicating code in a repository the error

> Error: 'c' is used outside the scope of its declaration

occurs when attempting to insert DQL with conditions into a QueryBuilder.

The basic entities include Household and Contact. Calculations are based on contact date range, site (location of contact), and type (type of contact). There is a service that creates an array of where clauses and query parameters, as will be evident in the code below.

I know the calculation works if all the code occurs in a single function. It seems the problem arises from the join with the Contact entity and its necessary constraints. Can DRY be accomplished in this scenario?

All of the following appear in the Household entity's repository.

The DQL is:

```
private function reportHousehold($criteria)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i.id')
            ->join('TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Contact', 'c', 'WITH',
                'c.household = i')
            ->where($criteria['betweenWhereClause'])
            ->andWhere($criteria['siteWhereClause'])
            ->andWhere($criteria['contactWhereClause'])
            ->getDQL()
    ;
}
```

Example of $criteria: `$criteria['betweenWhereClause'] = 'c.contactDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate'`

One of the calculations on Household:

```
public function res($criteria)
{
    $parameters = array_merge(
        $criteria['betweenParameters'], $criteria['siteParameters'],
        $criteria['startParameters'], $criteria['startParameters'],
        $criteria['contactParameters']);
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('h.id, 12*(YEAR(:startDate) - h.arrivalyear) + (MONTH(:startDate) - h.arrivalmonth) Mos')
            ->from('TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Household', 'h')
            ->distinct()
//DQL inserted here:
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('h.id', $this->reportHousehold($criteria)))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('h.arrivalyear'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('h.arrivalmonth'))
            ->andWhere($criteria['startWhereClause'])
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sense Preciel is correct: the solution does require the use of `$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()`. Instead of injecting DQL as a subquery, the trick is to return an array of ids and use the array in an IN clause. The effect is to remove any consideration of entities other than the Household entity from the calculation. Here's the result:

```
public function res($criteria)
{
    $parameters = array_merge($criteria['startParameters'], $criteria['startParameters'], ['hArray' => $this->reportHousehold($criteria)]);
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('h.id, 12*(YEAR(:startDate) - h.arrivalyear) + (MONTH(:startDate) - h.arrivalmonth) Mos')
            ->from('TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Household', 'h')
            ->distinct()
            ->where('h.id IN (:hArray)')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('h.arrivalyear'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('h.arrivalmonth'))
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;
}

private function reportHousehold($criteria)
{
    $parameters = array_merge($criteria['betweenParameters'], $criteria['siteParameters'], $criteria['contactParameters']);
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select('i.id')
            ->join('TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Contact', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.household = i')
            ->where($criteria['betweenWhereClause'])
            ->andWhere($criteria['siteWhereClause'])
            ->andWhere($criteria['contactWhereClause'])
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either missing `getRepository()` or `from()`

Try this (my prefered choice) :

```
private function reportHousehold($criteria) {
    return $this->getEntityManager
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("i.id")
                ->from(YourEntity::class, "i")
                ->join("TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Contact", "c", "WITH", "c.household=i.id")
                ->where($criteria['betweenWhereClause'])
                ->andWhere($criteria['siteWhereClause'])
                ->andWhere($criteria['contactWhereClause'])
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();
}
```

Or this

```
private function reportHousehold($criteria) {
    return $this->getEntityManager
                ->getRepository(YourEntity::class)
                ->createQueryBuilder("i")
                ->select("i.id")
                ->join("TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Contact", "c", "WITH", "c.household=i.id")
                ->where($criteria['betweenWhereClause'])
                ->andWhere($criteria['siteWhereClause'])
                ->andWhere($criteria['contactWhereClause'])
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();
}
```

Careful, I'm assuming you're on Symfony 3 or above.
If not, replace `YourEntity::class` by Symfony 2 syntax which is `"YourBundle:YourEntity"`

Comment: I'd hoped it was clear that `reportHousehold($criteria)` appeared in the Household repository. When in an entity's repository the expression `$this->createQueryBuilder('i')` assumes the current entity. So in my code above `$this->createQueryBuilder('i')` refers to the Household entity and no `->from(...)` is required. I will make my question clearer on this point.

Comment: While it's in the "right" repository, it doesn't mean that you don't have to specify some form of `FROM` clause. Either with `getRepository()` or with `from()`. Your repository is simply an extension of your entity. Have you tried the code?

Comment: No change. The from clause is required if one uses `$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()`. Try not using a from clause with `$this->createQueryBuilder($alias)` in a repository to demonstrate .